# How to change a:link and a:hover for a div alone?

Tags: css

In my page's body I already have an `a:link` and `a:hover`.

But now I have another div tag where I want different `a:link`, `a:hover` and `a:visited`.

How do I do this?

Comment: Please can you show your code, then we can give you a very helpful answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In CSS:

```
div.classname a:link {
  color: #123456;
}

div.classname a:hover {
  color: #123;
}

div.classname a:visited {
  color: #654321;
}
```

In HTML:

```
<div class="classname">
  <a href="#link">link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Assign a class for the div. something like

```
<div>
    <a></a> //style from a:link and a:hover
</div>
<div class="my-div">
    <a></a> //style from a:link and a:hover overridden by styles from .my-div a:link and .mydiv a:hover
</div>
```

Style

```
a:link{} //old link
a:hover{}


.my-div a:link{} //second link
.my-div a:hover{}
```

You can chain the css selectors to form different combinations of styles

Answer (score 0):

You could use the child selector method:

```
div.one > a { color:blue; }
div.two > a { color:red; }
```

will work for

```
<div class=''><a>link</a></div>
```

but not

```
<div class=''><p><a>link</a></p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use !important like this if above code is not working

```
.classname > a:hover{color:red !important;}
.classname > a:link{color:red !important;}
.classname > a:visited{color:red !important;}
```